# How to get position of the entity after animation has occurred in aframe?

Tags: aframe

I've tried out multiple ways including the [documentation of aframe for position](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/camera.html#reading-position-or-rotation-of-the-camera). I have also tried conventional `getAttribute` method but every time I am getting the position assigned hard-coded by me.

```
<a-entity class="rota" id="duck1" color="#FF0000" scale="0.1 0.1 .1" position="2 0 -7" animation="property: rotation;from: ; to:0 -360 0; loop:true; easing:linear; dur:30000; pauseEvents: mouseenter; resumeEvents: starteventforAnimation " animation__mouseenter="property: rotation;from: ; to:0 360 0; easing:linear; dur:4000; startEvents: mouseenter ;pauseEvents: starteventforAnimation; resumeEvents: mouseenter" eventhandling>
            <a-box class="rota" color="#FF0000" gltf-model="spaceship.glb"  position="20 0 -10"  scale="2 3 3" collison-check="el: #otherduck; radius: 0.15; other-radius: 0.15;"> </a-box>
        </a-entity>
```

The position assigned in first line of code is `2 0 -7`. Even after multiple animations triggered by event `mouseenter` the position of the entity in my console log still shows the hard-coded position.

I have also attached the program and showed all the ways as told by documentation. Please see the log entry in console. I have also tried solutions from stackoverflow but none of them were usefull.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('eventhandling', {
            tick: function () {
                var el = this.el;
              var entity = document.querySelector('#duck1');
                el.addEventListener('animationcomplete', function(){
                    console.log("getAttribute: "+Object.values(el.getAttribute('position')));
                  console.log("object3D.position: "+Object.values(el.object3D.position));
                  console.log("object3D.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3()): "+Object.values(el.object3D.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3())));
                   entity.emit('starteventforAnimation'); 
                });
          }
        });
    
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene>
<a-entity class="rota" id="duck1" color="#FF0000" scale="0.1 0.1 .1" position="2 0 -7" animation="property: rotation;from: ; to:0 -360 0; loop:true; easing:linear; dur:30000; pauseEvents: mouseenter; resumeEvents: starteventforAnimation " animation__mouseenter="property: rotation;from: ; to:0 360 0; easing:linear; dur:4000; startEvents: mouseenter ;pauseEvents: starteventforAnimation; resumeEvents: mouseenter" eventhandling>
            <a-box class="rota" color="#FF0000" gltf-model="spaceship.glb"  position="20 0 -10"  scale="2 3 3" collison-check="el: #otherduck; radius: 0.15; other-radius: 0.15;"> </a-box>
        </a-entity>
<a-camera position="0 1.2 1.3"><a-cursor objects=".rota" ></a-cursor></a-camera>        <

    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```